# List files of specific file type and directories

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to create a script that looks into a specific directory and then lists all the files of my chosen types in addition to all folders within the original location.

I have managed the first part of listing all the files of the chosen types, however am encountering issues listing the folders.

The code I have is:

```
import datetime, os

now = datetime.datetime.now()

myFolder = 'F:\\'
textFile = 'myTextFile.txt'

outToFile = open(textFile, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')


filmDir = os.listdir(path=myFolder)

for file in filmDir:
    if file.endswith(('avi','mp4','mkv','pdf')):
        outToFile.write(os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '\n')
    if os.path.isdir(file):
        outToFile.write(os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '\n')

outToFile.close()
```

It is successfully listing all avi/mp4/mkv/pdf files, however isn't ever going into the `if os.path.isdir(file):` even though there are multiple folders in my F: directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if it is suggesting a more effective/efficient method entirely that does the job.

Solution found thanks to Son of a Beach

```
if os.path.isdir(file):
```

changed to

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(myFolder, file)):
```

Comment: Have you checked (eg with `print`) what the value of `file` is?  Is it fully qualified?  relative path?  just a filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the names of the files, not the fully-qualified paths to the files.

You should use a fully qualified path name in `os.path.isdir()` (unless you've already told Python where to look).

Eg, instead of using `if os.path.isdir(file):` you could use:

```
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(myFolder, file)):
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. Edited to ` if os.path.isdir(filmFolder+file):` and it's working perfectly

Comment: I just edited that was trying to put more generic variable names and must have missed that one when editing thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that `myFolder+file` may work fine in your case if `myFolder` already has the correct path separator at the end.  In general, `os.path.join(myFolder, file)` is safer as it works wether `myFolder` ends with the correct path separator or not (and works in any environment, no matter what the correct path separator for the current OS is).